# VBA does not click <a> within <li>

Tags: html, vba

I am navigating to a webpage with an unordered list. Now I have to click an 'anchor' tag within a specific 'li' tag.

The part of the source code is,

```html
<UL class="x-tab-strip x-tab-strip-top" id=ext-gen151>
  <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_pubst_pubstructStructureGWT _nodup="30817">
    <A class=x-tab-strip-close></A>
    <A class=x-tab-right href="#">
      <EM class=x-tab-left>
<SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner>
<SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Structure</SPAN>
</SPAN>
</EM>
    </A>
  </LI>
</UL>
```

The anchor tag does not have a name or ID and has a class name(" x-tab-right ").

I tried the following vba code for simulating a click on that tag,

```
Dim targetSpan As HTMLObjectElement
Set targetSpan = doc.getElementById("infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_pubst_pubstructStructureGWT").getElementsByTagName("a")(1)
targetSpan.click
```

**=> Code :**

```
Dim AllSpanElements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim spanCounter As Long
Set AllSpanElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("li")
For spanCounter = 0 To AllSpanElements.Length - 1
With AllSpanElements(spanCounter)
    If (.innerText) = "Structure" Then
                .ParentElement. ParentElement.ParentElement.Click
        Exit For
    End If
End With
Next
```

I got the 2nd code from StackOverflow.

Both the code doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The href "#" will do just that. Nothing!
If you can edit the page, replace # with a live link and test again.

Comment: @peakpeak when I manually click on the tab 'Structure', even though the link remains the same, I am getting a directory.

Comment: @peakpeak I am supposed to go to that directory through program

Comment: I cannot change the source code